# How can i change the text color in a UISegmented Control in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

The only solution that i can think of so far is by adding images.. but i want the right solution...so i there any way to change the text/title color???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.framewreck.net/2010/07/custom-tintcolor-for-each-segment-of.html

On this post there is the implementation of a category that does what you are looking for.

From iOS SDK, there is no method to do this directly.

Comment: hey...thanks a lot ...this worked...but will this cause any rejection by apple ?? I have made an extension of this class and now i am able to set the text color.. :) If you don't mind can u tell me what is the difference between a category and an extension?

Comment: I wouldn't cause a rejection by Apple, because it's not using any private methods or API. Although since the whole customization is done navigating through the UISegmentedControl hierarchy, it could stop working, on future releases of the iOS, if Apple changes the structure of UISegmentedControl.

Comment: Categories and Extensions (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1)

Comment: If you consider my answer as correct click on the check-mark on the left side of my answer to set it as correct.

Answer (score 4):

use this method, it is in ios 5.x

```
UIFont *Boldfont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:Boldfont,UITextAttributeFont,[UIColor darkTextColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,nil];
    [self.mSegmentControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes 
                                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I wrote the same code and wrote another line for foState:UIControlStateHighlighted and I gave that bold and I gave the normal one normal system font. For some rason this isn't working, can you tell me why?